# OS X network service order doesn't stick

Tags: macos, network, internet

Under `System Preferences -> Network -> Set Service Order...` (OS X 10.9.4) I changed the order for the configured network services to my desires. However, every time my 3G modem connects to the internet it is set as the first service and the order is reverted. (I experience something similar with a VPN service.) This is really annoying since I have a limited data plan on my 3G modem and do *not* want to use it if a wireless network is available.

How can I make the service order stay as I configured it?

[Edit] Here is what my console says:

```
com.apple.kextd[12] Kext id com.huawei.driver.HuaweiDataCardDriver not found; removing personalities from kernel.
com.apple.kextd[12] String/URL conversion failure.
kernel[0]   USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 0x12d1 0x1f01 0x102, 2
kernel[0]   SAM Multimedia: READ or WRITE failed, SENSE_KEY = 0x05, ASC = 0x20, ASCQ = 0x00
kernel[0]   SAM Multimedia: READ or WRITE failed, SENSE_KEY = 0x05, ASC = 0x20, ASCQ = 0x00
kernel[0]   SAM Multimedia: READ or WRITE failed, SENSE_KEY = 0x05, ASC = 0x20, ASCQ = 0x00
kernel[0]   SAM Multimedia: READ or WRITE failed, SENSE_KEY = 0x05, ASC = 0x20, ASCQ = 0x00
kernel[0]   SAM Multimedia: READ or WRITE failed, SENSE_KEY = 0x05, ASC = 0x20, ASCQ = 0x00
kernel[0]   hfs: mounted HiLink on device disk2s0s2
mds[35] (Normal) Volume: volume:0x7fd1899b1800 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:1 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:(null) occlude:0 /Volumes/HiLink
Finder[209] FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
Finder[209] FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
kernel[0]   hfs: unmount initiated on HiLink on device disk2s0s2
kernel[0]   USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 0x12d1 0x14dc 0x102
kernel[0]   0        1 AppleUSBCDCACMData: start - Find CDC driver for ACM data interface failed
kernel[0]   AppleUSBCDCECMData: Version number - 4.2.1b5, Input buffers 8, Output buffers 32
UserEventAgent[189] FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
acvpnagent[65]  A new network interface has been detected.
acvpnagent[65]  Function: logInterfaces File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/Routing/InterfaceRouteMonitorCommon.cpp Line: 477 IP Address Interface List: FE80:0:0:0:CABC:C8FF:FE8C:B25 192.168.178.25 10.205.42.230 FE80:0:0:0:10F8:D6FF:FE7F:A9EF 
acvpnagent[65]  Function: netInterfaceNoticeCategoryHandler File: ../../vpn/Agent/MainThread.cpp Line: 7388 Network Interface change detected, refreshing physical MAC addresses
kernel[0]   AppleUSBCDC: Version number - 4.2.1b5
mbbservice[172] FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
mbbservice[172] FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
mbbservice[172] FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
mbbservice[172] FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
mbbservice[172] FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
kernel[0]   Ethernet [AppleUSBCDCECMData]: Link up on en4, 10-Megabit, Full-duplex, No flow-control, Port 1, Debug [0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000]
mbbservice[172] FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
mbbservice[172] FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
acvpnagent[65]  Function: GetPrimaryInterfaceIndex File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 422 Unable to get global IPv6 information from system configuration.
acvpnagent[65]  Function: determinePublicAddrCandidateFromDefRoute File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 1769 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr::FindDefaultRouteInterface Return Code: -24117215 (0xFE900021) Description: ROUTETABLE_ERROR_GETBESTROUTE_FAILED 
acvpnagent[65]  Function: updatePotentialPublicAddresses File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 1914 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr::determinePublicAddrCandidateFromDefRoute Return Code: -24117215 (0xFE900021) Description: ROUTETABLE_ERROR_GETBESTROUTE_FAILED 
acvpnagent[65]  Function: testNetwork File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 669 Invoked Function: CNetInterface::GetGatewayAddress Return Code: -32636905 (0xFE0E0017) Description: NETINTERFACE_ERROR_SERVICE_ID_NOT_FOUND 
mbbservice[172] FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
acvpnagent[65]  Function: logProbeFailure File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1418 The HTTPS probe to 193.197.62.142 resulted in a redirect.
acvpnagent[65]  Function: analyzeHttpResponse File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1602 SG (193.197.62.142) contacted
mbbservice[172] FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
mbbservice[172] FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
mbbservice[172] FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
acvpnagent[65]  A new network interface has been detected.
acvpnagent[65]  Function: logInterfaces File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/Routing/InterfaceRouteMonitorCommon.cpp Line: 477 IP Address Interface List: FE80:0:0:0:CABC:C8FF:FE8C:B25 192.168.178.25 10.205.42.230 FE80:0:0:0:10F8:D6FF:FE7F:A9EF 192.168.8.100 
acvpnagent[65]  Function: netInterfaceNoticeCategoryHandler File: ../../vpn/Agent/MainThread.cpp Line: 7388 Network Interface change detected, refreshing physical MAC addresses
configd[55] network changed: v4(en0:192.168.178.25, en4+:192.168.8.100) DNS* Proxy SMB
mbbservice[172] FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
configd[55] network changed: v4(en4!:192.168.8.100, en0) DNS! Proxy SMB
configd[55] FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
kernel[0]   flow_divert_kctl_disconnect (0): disconnecting group 1
sudo[2568]      root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=ben ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/open -a /Library/StartupItems/MobileBrServ/mbbserviceopen.app
open[2569]  FAILURE: Failed to open property list at file:///private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist for reading. (The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied)
open[2569]  launch_msg(): Socket is not connected
xpcd[214]   Info.plist does not contain an XPCService dictionary: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/XPCServices/SecurityAgent.xpc
AirPlayUIAgent[879] 2014-09-12 01:23:42.127994 AM [AirPlayUIAgent] Changed PIN pairing: no
AirPlayUIAgent[879] 2014-09-12 01:23:42.177661 AM [AirPlayUIAgent] Changed PIN pairing: no
acvpnagent[65]  Function: GetPrimaryInterfaceIndex File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 422 Unable to get global IPv6 information from system configuration.
acvpnagent[65]  Function: determinePublicAddrCandidateFromDefRoute File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 1769 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr::FindDefaultRouteInterface Return Code: -24117215 (0xFE900021) Description: ROUTETABLE_ERROR_GETBESTROUTE_FAILED 
acvpnagent[65]  Function: updatePotentialPublicAddresses File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 1914 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr::determinePublicAddrCandidateFromDefRoute Return Code: -24117215 (0xFE900021) Description: ROUTETABLE_ERROR_GETBESTROUTE_FAILED 
acvpnagent[65]  The client's public address is now set to 192.168.8.100
acvpnagent[65]  Function: netInterfaceNoticeCategoryHandler File: ../../vpn/Agent/MainThread.cpp Line: 7388 Network Interface change detected, refreshing physical MAC addresses
acvpnagent[65]  Function: testNetwork File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 669 Invoked Function: CNetInterface::GetGatewayAddress Return Code: -32636905 (0xFE0E0017) Description: NETINTERFACE_ERROR_SERVICE_ID_NOT_FOUND 
acvpnagent[65]  Function: logProbeFailure File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1418 The HTTPS probe to 193.197.62.142 resulted in a redirect.
acvpnagent[65]  Function: analyzeHttpResponse File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 1602 SG (193.197.62.142) contacted
com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[2489]    FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[2489]    FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[2489]    FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[2489]    FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[2489]    FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[2489]    FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[2489]    FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[2489]    FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[2489]    FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[2489]    FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[2489]    FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[2489]    FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[2489]    FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
com.apple.preference.network.remoteservice[2489]    FIXME: IOUnserialize has detected a string that is not valid UTF-8, "���".
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see the log in your Console at the time of the event.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify that your changes have been saved in the preferences file located here

```
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/
```

File name: `com.apple.airport.preferences.plist`

First look at the time stamp for the file (it should reflect your time of changes)

next open that file (do not change anything) and in the Edit use the Find, type your network name and it should be in the top part of the document.

If NOT:

Your preferences changes are not been saved due:

Possibly your user permissions (ACLs) need refreshing.

Comment: I think you meant `NetworkInterfaces.plist`? I am not trying to change the order of the wireless networks (which is what is apparently stored in `com.apple.airport.preferences.plist`), but the order of the network interfaces. Resetting the ACLs did not help.

Comment: And yes, the preference file for the interfaces is written correctly, but changed back as soon as my modem connects.